# Why am I still getting a save prompt?

Tags: excel, vba

When I close my excel file, I ask the user to take a survey if they have Microsoft Outlook installed. The program works great and I receive the email with the survey results. However, they are still prompted with the "Do you want to save this document?" I have used my previous code to stop this prompt from coming up and it is...

```
Me.Saved = True
```

This has worked prior to this. However, the saving prompt still comes up. I am wondering why this is happening.

Here is my entire code from the BeforeClose Worksheet declaration. I have also used ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True, ThisWorkbook.Saved = True; however, the prompt still comes up...

UserForm2.Show goes to my userform that prompts the survey.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
UserForm2.Show
Me.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue? Did you by any chance recently install any add-ins which could be interfering?

Comment: nope...I have not installed anything recently...

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate this issue on my system, as your code seems to be working.

Have you tried adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` after `Me.Saved = True` ?

Comment: It still pops up with the save function...

I also took out my survey userform. Saved the excel document, reopened it and closed it without doing anything and it asked if I wanted to save it...If i didnt change a thing, it shouldn't ask me to save it... right?

Comment: Are there any calculations happening?

Comment: It will ask to save if there is something happening in the background. That would mean a function automatically executing on workbook open, on cell change, etc...

Comment: Try adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` **before** the `Me.Saved = True` line.

Comment: I was thinking the same as Siddharth Rout pointed out in his comment : The wrong add-ins may have been installed. I'd suggest uninstalling all PDF printers present, and trying again. If no improvement is made, I'd advise re-installing a PDF add-in (I have no issues on my system using PDFLite)

Comment: I tried Application.DisplayAlerts = False...it did not work

Here is my theory...

I have parameters that use pivot tables and hard coded VBA code that is embedded into the excel program...Every time I open up the document, it has to run the code and figure out what parameters are being met. Every single time the document opens it has to figure that out. I am wondering if that could be the culpurt to something changing in my excel document.